# Mex can't find g++

Tags: c++, matlab, g++, mex

I'm totally new to MatLab, I'm trying to compile a .cpp file using mex through the Matlab on redhat. Follwing is the output of my command

**mex myfile.cpp -v**

```
No MEX options file identified; looking for an implicit selection.
... Looking for compiler 'g++' ...
... Executing command 'which g++' ...Yes ('/bin/g++').
... Executing command 'g++ -print-file-name=libstdc++.so' ...Yes ('/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/libstdc++.so').
... Executing command 'g++ -dumpversion' ...Yes ('4.8.5').
... Executing command 'which g++' ...Yes ('/bin/g++').
... Looking for folder '' ...No.

Did not find installed compiler 'g++'.
Error using mex
No supported compiler was found. For options, visit https://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers.
```

How can I get this file compiled?

**wheris g++** output

```
g++: /usr/bin/g++ /usr/share/man/man1/g++.1.gz
```

MatLab version is 2018R

Comment: Maybe its because `gcc-4.8.5` is very old.

Comment: @drescherjm Should I upgrade the g++ version?

Comment: The link from the error message you posted shows support for `gcc-6.3`. https://www.mathworks.com/support/requirements/supported-compilers.html

Comment: ***Should I upgrade the g++ version?*** Yes

Comment: Seems that is the issue :) Thanks you very mcuh. If you put this as an answer I will accept )

Comment: Also, always do `mex -setup` so you know if MATLAB is actually detecting it

Comment: I did the setup, but it didn't work either :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of `gcc-4.8.5` is too old. The link from the error message http://mathworks.com/support/requirements/supported-compilers.html lists support for gcc-6.3.X on linux. Please upgrade your compiler to gcc-6.3 or greater.